# Why would an intelligent dragon kidnap a princess or prince?

Tags: society, mythical-creatures

I am looking to write a part of my book were an intelligent dragon kidnaps the hero. So the question is: why would a benevolent and intelligent dragon kidnap someone?

Comment: Please see https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6338/21222. As it is this question is off-topic for World Building.

Comment: This is really something *you* need to work out, not least because only *you* know the motivations of your characters in your book.  As it stands your question is as close to "Why did the chicken cross the road ?" as makes no difference.  And note that kidnapping someone *is* harming them, that's why it's a crime.  An intelligent dragon really ought to know that.  :-)

Comment: The clear answer, for the princess, is that the king is a tyrant and trying to marry her off to someone she hates.  So she makes a deal with the dragon to kidnap her so she doesn't have to marry the bad guy.

Comment: The prince in question is Prince Charming from _Shrek_. The dragon is providing a public service

Comment: If you're asking  a "why" question, you're seeking an opinion based answer. Either that, or we can role-play and I'll be the Dragon and you have to accept whatever answer I give you. Neither of those options is how WB.SE works. Even though WB tends to favour a certain amount of opinion in its answers, this query should remain closed until you figure out how to turn it into less of an opinion quagmire!

Answer (score 5):

A few different options here:

1. Ransom. As ActionEconomy (whose answer is also good) alluded to, dragons tend to hoard things of value, and the dragon as an intelligent creature could easily recognize that she could get a good addition to her hoard by kidnapping him and demanding the regent pay to get him back.
2. Leverage. Perhaps the regent has been enroaching upon the dragon's territory or something she considers hers, and she has kidnapped the prince in order to get them to back off. (There could be an additional explanation as to why she doesn't just go in and use her dragonly might to chase them off, such as potential damage to a resource she wants, restraint on her part, etc.)
3. The prince ran afoul of her in some way, potentially without realizing it. Perhaps he commanded an expedition into her lair which took something of hers, and she considers him to owe her a debt which can be served in this way.
4. Bragging rights. Perhaps it's common for dragons to show off to other dragons by seizing things or people of value from military kingdoms, and she's just trying to impress her neighbors.

Comment: The fact that all four answers are Very Good indicates that the question is Too Broad.

Answer (score 2):

**Make babies**

Hey the specifics of how that mythological beast reproduces has largely been shrouded in ambiguity. Why not need a human man to make dragon babies.

One variant among many of dragons is that they are cursed humans anyways.

It wouldn't be far fetched for a cursed woman to vent thousands of years of pent up sexual frustration on some knight and shining armor.

Comment: If dragons were really women, KISAs would be fighting **to have sex with them**, not the reverse!!  "My awesome virility -- worthy of searching for the Holy Grail -- will break the curse and return her to Mother Church!"

Comment: @RonJohn Whoa now your making some leaps that I never agreed to. I never said anything about this "kissing the frog" concept where the dragon turns back to a human female. No I meant its a human female trapped in a dragons body and wanting some love. I cant imagine many men wanting that with a enormous, man eating, scaly reptile.

Comment: I'm putting my feet in the shoes of a medieval knight.  How would proud, full-of-themselves Knights (real ones, not the wimpy knighthoods they issue today) react if they knew that dragons were really women who wanted to have sex?

Comment: I suppose where will meets desperation, love happens....... Though I will point out knights where largely a Christian construct and in Christianity sex with a beast is considered an unnatural act and therefore a sin. Then again so is murder yet they managed to justify slaughtering women and children.

Answer (score 1):

In most high fantasy, dragons hoard "things of value", not just gold, but silver, rubies, jewelry, armor of dead adventurers etc. Perhaps the dragon recognises he is valuable in general and just wants to add him to the hoard of valuables.